# Getting NoClassDefFoundError in Java

Tags: java, classpath

I am learning about `classpath` in java. I created a package called `Geometry` which is stored in `C:\Java\` containing one file Point.java which contains the following code

```
package Geometry;

public class Point 
{
    double x;
    double y;

    public Point(double xVal, double yVal) 
    {
        x = xVal;
        y = yVal;
    }

    public Point(final Point oldPoint) 
    {
        x = oldPoint.x;
        y = oldPoint.y;
    }

    void move(double xDelta, double yDelta)
    {
        x += xDelta;
        y += yDelta;
    }

    double distance(final Point aPoint)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(  Math.pow((x - aPoint.x), 2) + Math.pow((y - aPoint.y), 2)  );
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }

}
```

Then i created another file in `C:\Users\username\workspace\Test` called `Test.java`

Which contains the following

```
import Geometry.*;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        Point l1 = new Point(1,2,3,4);
        System.out.println(l1);
    }

}
```

Then compiling using

```
C:\Users\username\workspace\Test>javac -cp c:\Java Test.java
```

It compiles successfully but throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` exception error in run time. What is the problem

Comment: how do you launch your program? Do you add the proper classpath, same as when compiling?

Comment: @JPMoresmau i compile using javac -cp c:\Java Test.java and then running using java Test. Is there any error

Comment: Do you have a directory named "Geometry" with Line.class in it?

Comment: java -classpath C:\Java Test

Comment: @JPMoresmau when i trid this it said "Error: Could not find or load main class Test"

Comment: `java -cp "C:\Java;." Test` should do the trick

Comment: ah sorry, java -classpath c:\Java;. Test, you need to pass as classpath all the folders at the root of your classes

Comment: @RC.thanks RC it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer given in comments by JP Moresmau and RC, putting it here for completion).

In Java, you need to specify a classpath both when compiling and when running. So when you compile with

```
javac -cp c:\Java Test.java
```

You're compiling the Test class in the current directory, using c:\Java as an EXTRA classpath parameter.

When you want to run the Test class, you need to tell Java where to find its own class (in the current directory) but also the required classes. If you just run

```
java Test
```

Java will use the current folder as the only classpath, and hence won't find the class referenced, that have been compiled in C:\Java. Hence you need to specify

```
java -cp "C:\Java;." Test
```

To indicate where to find all required classes.